# Could we be allowed to view deleted questions when linked from the meta site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**EDIT** Ah, I wasn't aware that >10,000 rep users could actually view deleted links.  Given this what should a lower than 10,000 rep user do to try and follow old meta questions where the links have been deleted?

As a possible solution to linking all deleted questions from meta, could we just allow links to work when the question has passed a vote threshold, say 5 upvotes and 1K views?

I've just started browsing the meta section of stackoverflow.  Looking at old questions one thing I notice is that often the links in those questions will point to stackoverflow questions that have been deleted.

This makes sense that there would be links to alot of deleted questions as these are the types of questions that get discussed in meta.  Unfortunately this means that lots of old meta questions and answers are hard to follow as the links no longer work.

Would it be possible to show deleted questions when coming from the meta site?  I think there is some value in this.

Comment: That's why we have [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges). Wouldn't giving people a back door through Meta sort of defeat the purpose?

Comment: you are already, "edit hack" does just that without any meta linking: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/128548/edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/128548/edit) "This post is intended to be a reference for the various comments made to new users asking them to change something about their post..." [http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16862801/edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16862801/edit) "I had a programming question come up today..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bad idea.

Actually, it's a good idea - with some bad consequences.

I'm <10k on SO. I can't see deleted stuff.

If this was implemented, I could see deleted stuff. Just make a meta post with a teeny-tiny link to it (like [t](http://google.com)his).

I can now see any deleted post I know the URL to just by making a one-letter link on meta.

Not good. The 10k'ers can't lord it over us any more.

*In response to your edit*: Ask a 10k'er to post a screenshot, if it's that urgent. Otherwise, go answer some more questions and get that 10k rep.

Comment: Or, even sneakier, [hide it in the whitespace](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182571/206222) of an existing link.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Oh wow - that's *scary*!

Comment: @Undo "Otherwise, go answer some more questions and get that 10k rep." :) Good advice, Working on it now

Comment: @chollida Go for it. You might even get some upvotes from a friend :)

Comment: @Undo. It won't work. Serial voting is reverted.

Comment: @Calmarius This is ancient, from a time when I was younger and stupider ;)